# Radius and Interval of Convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5^n}{n^2}x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{n^2}x^n$$

After doing the ratio test I end up with:

$$5|x| < 1$$

I'm confused, though, as to what is considered my interval of convergence and what is my radius.  I recognize that $1$ is my limit, so does this mean my radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{5}$ and my interval of convergence is:

$$\left(-\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5}\right)$$

Comment: $-1/5$ also counts. Which makes it a Leibniz series.

Comment: How can I determine if those values count in the interval? @Vim

Comment: @Vim Even $+1/5$ counts, since it converges to $\pi^2/6$ (see the Basel Problem)

Comment: by plugging them in for $x$ in your series and see what kind of series you get.

Comment: @JasonM absolutely. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ratio test you've shown that the interval of convergence may be $(-\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5})$.  To finish up plug in $x=\frac{1}{5}$ and $x=\frac{-1}{5}$.  The first is just, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{n^2}\frac{1}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ which converges by p-series test.  So at the very least you can say the interval of convergence is $(-\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5}]$.  Can you finish it up from here?

Comment: I see what you mean.  But shouldn't it be $n=1$?

Comment: You are correct!  I will edit that now, thank you!

Comment: So I checked $-\frac{1}{5}$ using the alternating series test and see that it is decreasing since $b_n \gt b_{n+1}$ and is convergent since the limit is $0$.  So this point is also included in my interval.

Comment: You are correct, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ converges and so both points are included.

Answer (score 2):

Why not directly Cauchy' Hadamard formula with the $\;n\,-$ the roots test?

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{5^n}{n^2}}=\frac5{\sqrt[n]{n^2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}5\implies R=\frac15$$

is the convergence radius, so the series converges for $\;-\frac15<x<\frac15\;$ . You can now check that at both extreme points the series is also convergent, so the interval of convergence is $\;\left[-\frac15,\,\frac15\right]\;$

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you'd find it less confusing if it were written like this:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{n^2} (x- 23)^n
$$
(where the number $23$ was chosen somewhat arbitrarily).

Instead of $5|x|<1$ you'd have $5|x-23|<1$, which implies  $|x-23|<\dfrac 1 5$, and that is equivalent to $-\dfrac 1 5 < x-23 < \dfrac 1 5$, and finally to $$23-\dfrac 1 5 < x < 23+\dfrac 1 5.$$  *Then* what would you take to be the interval of convergence?